Using Microphone in a WebView within a .NET MAUI Hybrid App for Audio Checks
I'm developing a .NET MAUI Hybrid application where I have a WebView component loading a website. This website requires access to the device's microphone for audio checks. However, I'm uncertain about the feasibility of accessing the microphone within the WebView context.
Is it possible to grant microphone access to a website loaded within a WebView in a .NET MAUI app? If so, what would be the recommended approach to achieve this functionality? Any insights, code snippets, or references would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
Note: i already allowed all the manifest permission like Record_Audio and Modify _Audio_Settings

There is a similar issue about this, you can check it first: Blazor MAUI - Camera/Microphone Android.
